# Splitting a CSV into two files by repeated cells Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

Any time that a row ID (oddly placed in column 8, i.e. row[7]) is repeated after the first instance, I want to write those rows into a second file.  The code I've tried is extremely slow -- it's a 40-column CSV with about a million rows.  This is what I have:

```
def in_out_repsplit(inf, outf1, outf2):
    outf1 = csv.writer(open(outf1, 'wb'), delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
    outf2 = csv.writer(open(outf2, 'wb'), delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
    inf1 = csv.reader(open(inf, 'rbU'), delimiter=',')
    inf1.next()
    checklist = []
    for row in inf1:
        id_num = str(row[7])
        if id_num not in checklist:
            outf1.writerow(row)
            checklist.append(id_num)
        else:
            outf2.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `in` operator does a linear search on a Python `list()`, since you only want membership testing, Python's `set()` is a more appropriate structure with average constant time membership tests. For a CSV with a million rows this small change should make things considerably faster.

```
def in_out_repsplit(inf, outf1, outf2):
    outf1 = csv.writer(open(outf1, 'wb'), delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
    outf2 = csv.writer(open(outf2, 'wb'), delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
    inf1 = csv.reader(open(inf, 'rbU'), delimiter=',')
    inf1.next()
    checklist = set()
    for row in inf1:
        id_num = str(row[7])
        if id_num not in checklist:
            outf1.writerow(row)
            checklist.add(id_num)
        else:
            outf2.writerow(row)
```

Also if `id_num` is an integer, use `int` instead of `str`. If `id_num` is in the range [0...N] (where N is reasonably close to the million rows), you can use a list of boolean values and get even faster look-ups.

```
    ...
    checklist = [False] * (MAXID + 1)
    for row in inf1:
        id_num = int(row[7])
        if not checklist[id_num]:
            outf1.writerow(row)
            checklist[id_num] = True
        else:
            outf2.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Wow.  For pure information sake, this changed the time of my code from about 45 minutes to 6.0 seconds.  Python is amazing.

Comment: I thought this was a good answer until I saw the suggestion of using a list of booleans with potentially one million entries...

Comment: @martineau can you explain why? In this case the boolean list is the most efficient for *both* storage and time. There is going to be a million items added to that set too.

Comment: Because a list of booleans, which is a subtype of integer, is such a blatant waste of space, when it's so easy to have a list of regular `int`s and do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22358133/355230) instead. While doing so would require computing an index and offset, that's only a [`divmod()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=divmod#divmod)-like operation, so there would be only a very minor speed penalty in accessing the individual bits. Whether a `set` would be just as bad depends on whether every possible `id_num` is encountered.

Comment: @rpattiso: ...and also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11023979/355230), which stores a bitmap in a single Python arbitrarily-long integer.

Comment: @martineau I suggested the Op use a set for membership testing as it is better than searching a list, then a list of bool values because it has a better worst-case look-up than the set. These are *algorithmic improvements* in complexity and both are readable and simple. Moving to bit twiddling and using ints to store multiple Truth values is premature optimization for this problem and not a very Pythonic solution either.

Comment: @rpattiso: Sorry, I don't consider reducing memory usage potentially 32-fold (or more) via extremely basic bit-manipulation techniques premature optimization regardless of the language involved.